# Auto generate token does not functioning properly in php

Tags: php, mysql, loops, random, auto-generate

I am now creating a project. In this I am stuck. I want that an 8 digit pin number is generate. If this pin is already in the database then another pin number is generated. After counting 100 times if in all 100 times the generated pin number is in the database then a 9 digit pin number is generated.
My Code is given below :

```
$t=$this->generate_string(8);
$th= Booking::Where('token',$t)->first();
$count = 0 ;
if(isset($th)) {
    if($count >= 100){
        $t   = $this->generate_string(9);
    }else{
        $t   = $this->generate_string(8);
    }
    $count++;
}
$booking->token = $t;
```

And generate_string function are

```
private function generate_string($length)
{
    $character = '0123456789';
    $character .= 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $quantity_character = strlen($character);
    $quantity_character--;
    $Hash = NULL;
    for ($x = 1; $x <= $length; $x++) {
        $position = rand(0, $quantity_character);
        $Hash .= substr($character, $position, 1);
    }
    return $Hash;
}
```

My code is not functioning properly. Please help me

Comment: How it is not function properly?

Comment: My $count variable is not incrementing. It can't check  if($count >= 100) is true or false. @developer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will not increment the counter because you did not do it.

I created an example based on your code, i used recursion to get the token.

**Generate Token Function:**

```
private function generate_string($length)
{
    $character = '0123456789';
    $character .= 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $quantity_character = strlen($character);
    $quantity_character--;
    $Hash = NULL;
    for ($x = 1; $x <= $length; $x++) {
        $position = rand(0, $quantity_character);
        $Hash .= substr($character, $position, 1);
    }
    return $Hash;
}
```

**Check token function:**

```
private function check_token($t){
    return Booking::Where('token',$t)->first();
}
```

**Get token function:**

```
private function get_token($length, $count){
    $t=$this->generate_string($length);

    $r = check_token($t);
    if(!isset($r)) // base case 1
        return $t;
    if($count <= 0) // base case 2
        return $this->generate_string(9);

    return $this->get_token($length, --$count); // decrements the $count and do recursion.
}
```

**Usage:**
`$token = $this->get_token(9, 5); //token length = 9, max tries = 5`

**Get token function** uses recursion to generate the token, how the recursion will stop? we have to base cases,

1. When `!isset(check_token($t))` mean that there is not possible token duplicate.
2. When `$count <= 0` mean that we reach the max possible tries.

If no one of base cases matched, the function call it self again with decremented `$count`.

Check and update it to fit your needs.

**UPDATE:**

To get token if the token matches `n` times, update the `get_token` function as following:

```
private function get_token($length, $count){
    $t=generate_string($length);

    $r = check_token($t);
    if(isset($r)){ // token matches, then decrements $count 
        --$count;
    }else{
        return $t; // token did not matched, then return the token
    }
    if($count <= 0) // if we reaches the max tries, return token of length '$length + 1'
        return $this->generate_string($length + 1); 

    return $this->get_token($length, $count);
}
```

Comment: I need that if the token matches 100 times then it increments the length by 1 that is 9 else the token will be 8 character long @developer

Comment: Your code will give me possible tries but I dont want it. I want that After 100 times the token will be 9 character long otherwise it will be 8 character long

Comment: You decrement the count. But I want incrementing. When the count is 100 times or more then it generate 9 digit token else it generate 8 digit token. How can i do this. I dont do any maximum tries. User can try as much as he can @developer

Comment: @JahidMahmud look at the code how executed `$token = $this->get_token(9, 5); //token length = 9, max tries = 5` when token match the code will try to generate tokens up to max 5 times then return a token with `$length + 1`, it does not matter increment or decrements the count as long as the code will do recursion for max `$count` time

Comment: Thank you so much for your help